KSM, WND transfer transaction fail, but DOT success
I used the same program, the same fullnode version, and the same Substrate API sidecar version to submit transfer transactions for DOT, KSM, and WND. Only DOT was successful. Two months ago, DOT, KSM, and WND all worked, but now KSM and WND are failing. The fullnode responds with
'
2024-06-12 05:47:42.686 ERROR tokio-runtime-worker runtime: panicked at /build/polkadot/runtime/westend/src/lib.rs:1730:1:
Bad input data provided to validate_transaction: Codec error.'
My full node version is 0.9.42, and the API sidecar version is 15.0.0. Why are KSM and WND failing recently?

What's the content of /build/polkadot/runtime/westend/src/lib.rs:1730:1

This is due a breaking change in the transaction format introduced in the new release 1.2.5 which was enacted in Kusama and Westend yesterday.
Also, you are running old versions of the node and Sidecar. For sure API Sidecar 15.0.0 won't be compatible with the new changes, please update both to the latest release.

Thanks, then I have another question

Where can I find information on how to construct the new transfer transaction?
I'm using the latest version of Substrate API Sidecar (v19.0.1) to connect to wss://westend-rpc.polkadot.io, which is the latest node version. However, how can I find the metadata hash?



My best bet is to check the RFC (https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/RFCs/blob/main/text/0078-merkleized-metadata.md) of this change where you find the specification of the changes  (also the relevant PR: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/4274).
You dont need to add the metadata hash unless you expect to tx to be signed in a Leger device. For the normal case, you just set mode = 0 in the extrinsic information.
Polkadot.js API, Polkadot-API, subxt and txwrapper libraries support already this change so you should be able to use them to construct txs without issue.


May I ask if there is a specification for the signature payload? Currently, the specification document I found does not contain information about the metadata hash and mode codec.
https://spec.polkadot.network/id-extrinsics

currently my scale codec order is method call, era, nonce, tip specVersion, txVersion, genesis, era hash
I don't know where to put the mode and metadata hash in this order

I've post another question for sign payload here
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/dot-ksm-transfer-sign-payload-order

thanks for opening the new question, it is true there is a lack of proper specs on how to build the new transaction and it has to be inferred from the code which is far from ideal.
