DOT, KSM transfer sign payload order
I want to know the scale codec order for sign payload cause currently I can't transfer WND, KSM right now
currently my codec order is
method call ->  era -> nonce -> tip -> specVer -> txVer -> genesis -> blockhash
I don't know where to put the mode and metadata hash in this order sequence.
also the mode codec type (like UINT16, UINT32 ...)
